# primefaces commandbutton update attribute works only once in wildfly 15

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, wildfly

I have a simple xhtml which only contains a commandbutton. When you press that commandButton it calls a method in a backing bean that prints a string, that's all.

The problem is that the commandbutton only calls the backing bean's method the first time you press it.

- No error on the server's log or in chrome console is shown.
- The same example works perfectly on tomcat.
- It works in wildfly if i remove  `update="form_test"`

**xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"           
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head> 
    <title>test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body style="background-color:black;" >

<h:form id="form_test">
    <p:commandButton 
    update="form_test"
    value="test agogo"
    action="#{testBean.test}"/>     
</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

**BB:**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean {
    public String test() {
        System.out.println("--- you pressed a button");
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you try running in development mode?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to pf 7.0 seems to solve the problem. However this solution may not be the best for a real life project because many interfaces from previous versions change and you may have to make a lot of code refactoring.

Comment: Upgrading from PrimeFaces 1.0 to 7.0 is the best solution for a real life project. And a `h:commandButton` with `f:ajax` inside it does work? And (offtopic I hope) your JSF namespaces are 'wrong' or JSF 2.3, please update them. And your bean annotations are deprecated too ;-) So upgrading more things is manybe the best thing to do.

Comment: And if you deploy the 100% identical project on tomcat you either have JSF implementation in your war or you configured it somewhere else. This is VERY important information for a real life project